# G is [property] if and only if N and G/N are both [property]

Tags: terminology

Is there a name for a property that is inherited by subgroups and quotients of a group?
How about a property that if true for both a normal subgroup N and the quotient G/N is true for G?
Or a name for the biconditional.

I know periodicity and solubility of groups satisfy the biconditional, and nilpotence is inherited by subgroups and quotients.

Can anyone provide any more examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a name for a property that is inherited by subgroups and quotients of a group?

I don't think so. You can say the property is preserved when taking subgroups and quotients.

> How about a property that if true for both a normal subgroup N and the quotient G/N is true for G?

It is a property that is preserved under *extensions*.

Comment: Do you know of any other interesting properties that are closed under taking extensions and/or inherited by subgroups and quotients?
Has there been any interest in this metaproperty?

For instance, I'm interested in why the biconditional "jumps" nilpotent groups. Obviously abelian groups have it, but nilpotent groups don't have closure under taking extensions even though nilpotence is a "subproperty" of solubility... It just seems strange.